# InfluxDB seems to be limiting the number of records I'm inserting

Tags: go, influxdb

My company has a remote InfluxDB instance that services are able to push records to. I'm pushing data directly using a Golang InfluxDB client, but when I query measurements, there is a pattern in the count that isn't accurate.

I'm running this query:

```
SELECT count("field_value") FROM "measurement_metrics" WHERE ("account_id" = 'account_value' AND "endpoint" = 'endpoint_value') AND time >= now() - 7d GROUP BY time(10m) fill(null)
```

and I'm getting results like this:

```
1618920600000000000 20
1618921200000000000 20
1618921800000000000 20
1618922400000000000 20
1618923000000000000 20
1618923600000000000 20
1618924200000000000 20
1618924800000000000 20
```

There are no empty rows on this field, and I can see from the database that this count should be in the millions per day, but I'm seeing it top out at ~2800 per day.

Is this a configuration issue on InfluxDB? My HTTP client is returning 200s, so I'm not sure where the issue is.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have millions of records for this field that have the matching `account_id` and `endpoint`?

Comment: Ya, I can query counts on how many account_id/endpoint jobs are inserted into our database and as long as they don't throw a nil pointer, the InfluxDB insert gets executed.